# Not able to select a value in a multiple select list box in Access when a query is assigned to the "on click" event

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba, buttonclick

I have two multiple select list boxes "Animal" and "State".  These two list boxes are dependent on each other.  For example, if i select "in" and "mi" in the state list box, the animal list box will only show animals that are in "in" and "mi".

My issue is i have the rowsource set to the query below which is assigned to the "on click" event in the animal list box.  When i click in the animal list box it runs the query but it no longer allows me to select any animals.

How do i change the list box to allow me to select animals in the animal list box?

```
Private Sub animal_Click()
 Dim Q           As QueryDef
    Dim DB          As Database
    Dim Criteria    As String
    Dim ctl         As Control
    Dim Itm         As Variant
    Dim ctl2        As Control
    Dim ctl3        As Control

    ' Use for dynamic SQL statement'
    Dim strSQL      As String



    Set ctl2 = Me![State]
    For Each Itm In ctl2.ItemsSelected
        If Len(Criteria2) = 0 Then
            Criteria2 = Chr(34) & ctl2.ItemData(Itm) & Chr(34)
        Else
            Criteria2 = Criteria2 & "," & Chr(34) & ctl2.ItemData(Itm) & Chr(34)
        End If
    Next Itm



    ' Modify the Query.
    Set DB = CurrentDb()
    Set Q = DB.QueryDefs("animal")
    ' Modify the Query.
    Set DB = CurrentDb()
    Set Q = DB.QueryDefs("animal")

    strSQL = "Select distinct(animal) From [table1] Where [table1].[type] In (" & "'Animal')"


    If (Len(Criteria2) <> 0) Then ' Append State Criteria
        strSQL = strSQL & " AND [table1].[state]  IN (" & Criteria2 & ")"
    End If

    Q.SQL = strSQL
    Q.Close

    ' Run the query.
    'DoCmd.OpenQuery "animalquery"
    Me.Animal.RowSource = strSQL
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i solved for this.

I originally changed "Private Sub animal_Click()" to "Private Sub animal_dblClick()"  but this was resulting in an event procedure error.

I then changed it to "Private Sub animal_Enter()".  When i enter the list box it runs the query while still allowing me to select items in the list box.

However, if someone has a different solution or know how to use the double click method. that would be great!